# OpenGL: glDrawArrays and glReadPixels in VBO

Tags: windows, opengl, nvidia, glreadpixels, gldrawarrays

I am trying to implement a VBO in which I use glDrawArrays to draw a list of triangles and glReadPixels to read the output. The glReadPixels function is throwing a segmentation fault error.

This is the code that initializes and uses the VBO:

```
void hemicube::draw_escena(vec3f center, vec3f lookat, vec3f up, bool transp) {
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(center.x, center.y, center.z, lookat.x, lookat.y, lookat.z, up.x, up.y, up.z);
if(primeraVez){
glInfo glInfo;
glInfo.getInfo();

    primeraVez=false;
    GLfloat* vertices = new GLfloat[e.surfaces.size()*9]; // create vertex array
    GLfloat* normals = new GLfloat[e.surfaces.size()*9]; // create vertex array

    unsigned char* colors = new unsigned char[e.surfaces.size()*4*3]; // create vertex array

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<e.surfaces.size(); ++i) {
        if (!(transp==1 & e.materials[e.surfaces[i].material].transparency==1)){
            unsigned int code = ~i;
            unsigned char* temp= (unsigned char*)&code;
            colors[i*4]  = temp[0];
            colors[i*4+1]= temp[1];
            colors[i*4+2]= temp[2];
            colors[i*4+3]= temp[3];

            colors[i*4+4]  = temp[0];
            colors[i*4+5]= temp[1];
            colors[i*4+6]= temp[2];
            colors[i*4+7]= temp[3];

            colors[i*4+8]  = temp[0];
            colors[i*4+9]= temp[1];
            colors[i*4+10]= temp[2];
            colors[i*4+11]= temp[3];
            for(unsigned int j=0; j<e.surfaces[i].vertices.size(); ++j){
                memcpy(vertices+(i*9+j*3),&e.vertices[e.surfaces[i].vertices[0]].x,3*sizeof(GLfloat));
            }
        }
    }

    glGenBuffersARB(1, &vboId);
    glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(vertices)+sizeof(colors), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
    glBufferSubDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);                             
    glBufferSubDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(vertices), sizeof(normals), normals);                // copy normals after vertices
    glBufferSubDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(vertices)+sizeof(normals), sizeof(colors), colors);  // copy colours after normals

    free(vertices);
    free(colors);
}

glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vboId);
// enable vertex arrays
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, (void*)(e.surfaces.size()*9*sizeof(GLfloat)));
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, (void*)(e.surfaces.size()*9*sizeof(GLfloat)*2));
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, e.surfaces.size()*3);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);  // disable vertex arrays
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);


glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
```

}

And this is the code that invokes that function and tries to read the result:

```
void hemicube::calc_form_factors(vec3f center, vec3f normal, vec3f up, vector<double>& form_factors) {
vec3f right = cross_prod(normal, up);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(90, 1, 0.001, 2000);
glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT |GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

GLint viewport[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);


// front
glViewport(resolution/2, resolution/2, resolution, resolution);
draw_escena(center-0.0001*normal, center+normal-0.0001*normal, up, 1);

// up
glViewport(resolution/2, resolution*3/2, resolution, resolution);
draw_escena(center-0.0001*normal, up+center-0.0001*normal, -normal, 1);

// right
glViewport(resolution*3/2, resolution/2, resolution, resolution);
draw_escena(center-0.0001*normal, center+right-0.0001*normal, up, 1);

// left
glViewport(-resolution/2, resolution/2, resolution, resolution);
draw_escena(center-0.0001*normal, center-right-0.0001*normal, up, 1);

// down
glViewport(resolution/2,-resolution/2,resolution, resolution);
draw_escena(center-0.0001*normal, center-up-0.0001*normal, normal, 1);

glViewport(viewport[0], viewport[1], viewport[2], viewport[3]);

glReadPixels(0, 0, resolution*2, resolution*2, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixel_buffer[0]);
}
```

Any thoughts on why is it not working?

*EDIT*
Pixel buffer is declared as:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> pixel_buffer;
```

and initialized with size 4*resolution*resolution

Comment: First guess would be that your `pixel_buffer` is not big enough for `4*resolution*resolution` RGBA pixels.

Comment: segmentation fault seems to originate in writing into the `pixel_buffer`, but you did not show any code concerning this array.

Comment: just edited with new info. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't studied the whole code, but you have a very obvious problem with your `glBufferData()` and `glBufferSubData()` calls. You're using `sizeof(vertices)` to determine the size, where `vertices` is a pointer. So the result will be 4 or 8, depending on whether you build a 32- or 64-bit executable. Same thing for all the other sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error:

I was missing a

```
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vboId);
```

after the

```
glGenBuffersARB(1, &vboId);
```

Also, I was handling the sizes in a wrong way, since those are not static arrays  but pointers.

Thanks to everybody,
Jose.